# MUI DatePicker - stop re-render when changing years

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to disable `onChange` when the user is switching from one year to another. The `DatePicker` updates a state variable, which is passed as a prop to another component. Right now, that component re-renders even when moving from year to year, before an actual date is selected by the user.

[image]

Current process:

1. The current selected date is February 14, 2022
2. User opens calendar, selects 2023
3. `DatePicker` immediately sets date to February 14, 2023 and re-renders the component
4. User picks the actual date in 2023 they wanted, and re-renders the component again

Can I remove #3 from the process? Maybe by overriding [`onYearChange`](https://mui.com/api/date-picker/)?

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how to do this, since there's `onYearChange` and `onMonthChange`, but then only a general `onChange` rather than something like `onDayChange`. I tried something like passing a function that returns nothing/false, but I don't think that was the correct way since it seemed to do nothing.

Below is my current code:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter = {AdapterDateFns}>
    <DatePicker
        value = {value}
        shouldDisableDate = {(date) => disableDates(date)}
        onChange = {(v) => handleChange(v)}
        renderInput = {(params) => <TextField {...params} />} />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from MU docs, seems like datepickers have a prop named `onAccept`, fired whenever the date is fully selected, in contrast to `onChange`, which is fired even when you change month or year.

By adding `onAccept`, adding an `onChange` props seems reduntant, but MU throws an error if `onChange` isn't defined. so I added a simple callback returning true, which I don't feel quite good about.

```
    <DatePicker
    value = {value}
    shouldDisableDate = {(date) => disableDates(date)}
    onAccept = {(v) => handleChange(v)}
    onChange={()=>true}
    renderInput = {(params) => <TextField {...params} />} />
```